# Vimperator. Setting plugin preferences

Tags: vimperator

When using plugins in Vimperator it's sometimes necessary to change preferences for them. For example, I use the [Mainecoon](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-plugins/blob/master/maine_coon.js) plugin which hides the command bar when it's inactive. By default Vimperator loads the plugin with the option *mainecoon=amu* but I want it to load with *mainecoon=a*. I write in *~/.vimperatorrc* the following:

```
set mainecoon=a
```

or

```
loadplugins
set mainecoon=a
```

but with no result.

How can I make Vimperator to read preferences for plugins on startup?